# PHP IMAP Decode UTF-8 email body

Tags: php, utf-8, imap

I have trouble with decoding email body with PHP.
I have 2 UTF-8 emails, which structures are identical.
For one I can decode the body with iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252", $data)
For the other one this doesn't work.
1) I don't know what to use instead of this
2) How can I identified differentiate the 2 types of emails dynamically ?

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => 1
    [encoding] => 0
    [ifsubtype] => 1
    [subtype] => MIXED
    [ifdescription] => 0
    [ifid] => 0
    [ifdisposition] => 0
    [ifdparameters] => 0
    [ifparameters] => 1
    [parameters] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [attribute] => BOUNDARY
                    [value] => ----=_Part_8432_30170987.1457360103746
                )
        )

    [parts] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => 0
                    [encoding] => 4
                    [ifsubtype] => 1
                    [subtype] => PLAIN
                    [ifdescription] => 0
                    [ifid] => 0
                    [lines] => 50
                    [bytes] => 1811
                    [ifdisposition] => 0
                    [ifdparameters] => 0
                    [ifparameters] => 1
                    [parameters] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [attribute] => CHARSET
                                    [value] => UTF-8
                                )

                        )

                )



        )

)


stdClass Object
(
    [type] => 1
    [encoding] => 0
    [ifsubtype] => 1
    [subtype] => MIXED
    [ifdescription] => 0
    [ifid] => 0
    [ifdisposition] => 0
    [ifdparameters] => 0
    [ifparameters] => 1
    [parameters] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [attribute] => BOUNDARY
                    [value] => ----=_Part_1135_19111967.1451925068339
                )

        )
    [parts] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => 0
                    [encoding] => 4
                    [ifsubtype] => 1
                    [subtype] => PLAIN
                    [ifdescription] => 0
                    [ifid] => 0
                    [lines] => 27
                    [bytes] => 490
                    [ifdisposition] => 0
                    [ifdparameters] => 0
                    [ifparameters] => 1
                    [parameters] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [attribute] => CHARSET
                                    [value] => UTF-8
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

When I use imap_mime_header_decode on both data objects I get this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [charset] => default
            [text] =>
...
)
```

Thanks in advance,
Stiti

Comment: Have you tried getting the character set from the mail header and converting to UTF8 from that (instead of assuming Windows-1252)?

Comment: Hello, the email charset in already UTF-8, but I want to convert it or at least print correctly the accents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved :
I used :

```
iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $data)
```

instead of :

```
iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252", $data)
```

And it works great now.